# Python Print Statement not returning PSL data

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have a code that is yielding a pretty wierd print statement. Here is my code:

```
import sys
class PSLreader :

    def __init__ (self, fname='EEV14-Cb.filtered.psl'):
        '''contructor: saves attribute fname '''

        self.fname = fname

    def doOpen (self):
        if self.fname is '':
            return sys.stdin
        else:
            return open(self.fname)

    def readPSL (self):
        '''
        using filename given in init, returns each filtered psl records
        that contain alignments that are within the terminal 1000nt of
        the target. Incomplete psl records are discarded.
        If filename was not provided, stdin is used.

        This method selects for alignments that could may be part of a
        circle.

        Illumina pairs aligned to the top strand would have read1(+) and read2(-).
        For the bottoms trand, read1(-) and read2(+).

        For potential circularity,
        these are the conditions that can support circularity:
        read1(+) near the 3' terminus
        read1(-) near the 5' terminus
        read2(-) near the 5' terminus
        read2(+) near the 3' terminus

        so...
        any read(+) near the 3', or
        any read(-) near the 5'

        '''

        nearEnd = 1000   # this constant determines "near the end"
        with self.doOpen() as fileH:

            for line in fileH:
                pslList = line.split()
                if len(pslList) < 17:
                    continue
                tSize = int(pslList[14])
                tStart = int(pslList[15])
                strand = str(pslList[8])

                if strand.startswith('+') and (tSize - tStart > nearEnd):
                    continue
                elif strand.startswith('-') and (tStart > nearEnd):
                    continue

                yield line

    def readPSLpairs (self):
        i = 0
        for psl in self.readPSL():
            if i>20:
                print(psl.split())
                i+=1
            else: 
                break

fileH = ("EEV14-Cb.filtered.psl")
new_psl = PSLreader(fileH)
print (new_psl.readPSLpairs())
```

And I'm getting "none" as my print statement. I think I've made some sort of a mistake in the last bit of code, but I'm not sure what it is. To give you some insight, I'm testing out some of my code and trying to have the "readPSLpars" method print out the first 20 lines of my PSL document. The "readPSL" part of the code just selects PSL lines that represent alignments in the first or last 1000 bases in the sequence, and I'm pretty sure that part of the code is okay. If anybody could let me know what's wrong with the last few lines of my code, that would be great.

**EDIT:** So should I make a generator that looks something like this:

```
gen = new_psl.readPSLpairs()            
for line in gen:
    new_psl = PSLreader("EEV14-Cb.filtered.psl")
    print (new_psl.readPSLpairs())
```

It still doesn't work, but that's because I always have issues with my syntax somewhere

**EDIT 2:** I changed my code to this, which brought up an error:

```
new_psl = PSLreader("EEV14-Cb.filtered.psl")
gen = new_psl.readPSLpairs()            
for line in gen:
    print (new_psl.readPSLpairs())
```

Error was: "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"

**EDIT 3:**

```
new_psl = PSLreader("EEV14-Cb.filtered.psl")
gen = new_psl.readPSLpairs()            
for line in gen:
     print line
```

"line" in "print line" gets highlighted when the syntax error comes up.

Answer (score 0):

readPSL will create an object that is consumed by readPSLpairs, which doesn't yield or return anything, so print output is correct.

The last two lines of your code should look like this

```
for line in gen:
    print line
```

It will allow you to see the first 20 lines that you were asking about.

Comment: I'm still not sure why I don't get the first 20 lines of the psl file, though. I mean, that's the purpose of readPSLpairs...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do in readPSLpairs. That method will read one line and quit the loop because of "break". Did I miss anything?

Comment: probably instead of "break" you meant "yield"? That would get the first 20 lines for you.

Comment: when I change "break" to "yield", I get an output of "<generator object readPSLpairs at 0x02A985D0>", which is kinda weird...

Comment: That's correct. To print out the lines, you would need to loop through it: gen = new_psl.readPSLpairs() and then iterate: for line in gen:

Comment: No. Inside the loop you should have one statement only: print line

Comment: Thanks, but I get invalid syntax when I use that. Edit 3 shows how I changed my code exactly.

Comment: What syntax error? If it's indentation,  change it to 4. I'm typing from a phone and could've mixed it up.

Comment: The only thing that was indented was "print line" in my edit.

Comment: it was a syntax error, and "line" was highlighted in "print line"

Comment: Can you run it from a command line and provide the output? There should be an explanation for the "syntax error".

Comment: I'm using IDLE... there's no explanation for the syntax error - I just get the message "invalid syntax". As I said, "line" was highlighted pink, so I guess something is wrong there. But it looks completely fine.